# How to increase size of File system root in ubuntu

Tags: filesystems, ubuntu-20.04

My /home partition is of size 350 GB and I have a lot of space remaining on it. I have just 16 GB space remaining on my **FileSystem Root**. I need to expand the Filesystem Root to install more softwares on my system. Is it possible? If yes, how?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOSyB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh7Uf.png)

Answer (score -1):

Dump the following commands from your machine to know the partition type clearly.

**lsblk**

**df -HT**

Comment: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh7Uf.png)

Please check the image

Comment: I want to increase the size of 55 GB partition.

Answer (score -1):

This command works for me

```
 sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Comment: That definitely does not do anything remotely like what the question is asking about.